# Can I capture a previously authorized payment transaction at a different amount?

Tags: credit-card, payment-processing, intuit-partner-platform

I'm using Quickbooks Merchant Services. We perform two-step card processing ... "authorize" to make sure their card and address are correct, and that they have the funds. Then we "capture" that transaction when they submit the confirmation page. Restaurants do this, so do many other vendors. But I don't think it's very common online.

When a customer enters an incorrect address more than once they end up with multiple auth/hold transactions, which makes them think we've charged them full price multiple times even though we have not.

Does anyone use QBMS to Authorize for a low amount -- perhaps $1 -- and then capture that transaction for the full amount later?

Hoping this will alleviate customer support complaints ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can only capture the amount you authorized *or less*. And you have 30 days to do it before the authorization expires.

Comment: Do you have a reference? Wikipedia suggests that it's possible, but might depend on the gateway and bank. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_hold#Holds_for_differing_amounts

Comment: It's definitely not possible in the US. Overseas it *may* be different. I worked for a merchant account provider for six years. It's just how they work. I know if you google it you can verify it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice is to authorize for zero value to verify the card details are correct, then at a later point auth and charge for the full amount.

What John said about capturing for auth amount or less is mostly correct, but there is a *slight* overhead allowed between the auth amount and final settlement amount. This basically only amounts to a few dollars though and is intended to cover cases where (eg) an order value changes due to shipping in separate installments